# Conditional expectation of a Geometric random variable conditioned on the event $A=\{X>3\}$

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a geometric random variable and let $A$ denote the event $\{X>3\}$ find the conditional probability mass function of $X$ with respect to the event $A$ and then compute $E[X\mid A]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that
$$
P(X=k)=p(1-p)^k,\quad k=0,1,2,\ldots
$$
and hence $P(X>3)=(1-p)^4$. Now if $k=0,1,2,3$, then of course $P(X=k\mid X>3)=0$ and if $k=4,5,\ldots$, then
$$
P(X=k\mid X>3)=\frac{P(X=k,X>3)}{P(X>3)}=\frac{P(X=k)}{P(X>3)}=p(1-p)^{k-4}.
$$
The conditional expectation is thus given by
$$
E[X\mid X>3]=\sum_{k=4}^\infty kP(X=k\mid X>3)=\sum_{k=4}^\infty kp(1-p)^{k-4}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+4)p(1-p)^k=4+E[X].
$$

Comment: There is something wrong here. Conditioned on $X>3$, the conditional expectation of $X$ is $3+E[X]$, not $E[X]$. If $p = 0.5$ so that $E[X]=2$, why should the _average_ value of $X$ be $2$ when we are _given_ that $X > 3$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Yes, you're absolutely right.

Comment: I edited my answer. Though I'm getting $4+E[X]$, but I think it depends on whether you define the geometric distribution on $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ or on $\{1,2,\ldots\}$.

Comment: Thank you! This really helped, hopefully I remember it on my final tomorrow!

Comment: How does it work for $\mathbb{E}[X \vert X \le b]$, that is, when the condition changes to $B = \{X \le b\}$?